# How to calculate period of the sinusoidal graph?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I want to calculate the period of the following graphs. I'm confused with the fact that `2π` is after few cycles. And there are numbers 1,2... instead of `π/2,π...`.

[image]

Comment: The period is given by $\dfrac{2\pi}{\textrm{how many repeating cycles you have until you hit } x=2\pi}$. For example, the first one has 5 repeated cycles up until $2\pi$, so the period is $\frac{2\pi}{5}$.

Comment: The angular frequency w is the number of full cycles between 0 and $2\pi$. The period is then the width of one cycle, which is $\frac{2\pi}{w}$.

Comment: @CheeHan So for the second graph it is 2π/2=π. Is it correct?

Comment: @gmailuser You are correct!

Comment: @CheeHan can you write please write as an answer?

Comment: @gmailuser Yes, for the second  it is $2pi/2=pi $

Comment: @CheeHan I've another graph where it hits 2π before completing full cycle. It hits 2π at almost 3/4 of cycle. How do I calculate in that case?

Comment: @gmailuser The same method applies too in this case!

Comment: @CheeHan So, I guess it would be 2π/(3/4)?

Comment: @gmailuser Yes (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period is given by 
$$ \frac{2\pi}{\textrm{How many repeated cycles you have until you hit }x=2\pi}. $$
For example, the first graph has 5 repeated cycles up until $2\pi$, so the period is $\dfrac{2\pi}{5}$.